# When did the main conjecture in Vinogradov's mean value theorem first appear in literature?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, ho.history-overview

Recently I was asked about the history of Vinogradov's mean value theorem that I was hoping someone here could clarify. Let me first start with some terminology. Let $J_{s, k}(X)$ be the number of $2s$-tuples $(x_1, \ldots, x_s, y_1, \ldots, y_s)$ such that
\begin{align*}
x_1 + \cdots + x_{s} &= y_{1} + \cdots + y_{s}\\
x_{1}^{2} + \cdots + x_{s}^{2} &= y_{1}^{2} + \cdots + y_{s}^{2}\\
&\vdots\\
x_{1}^{k} + \cdots + x_{s}^{k} &= y_{1}^{k} + \cdots + y_{s}^{k}
\end{align*}
for $1 \leq x_{i}, y_{i} \leq X$. It is not hard to see that $$J_{s, k}(X) \gtrsim_{s, k} X^{s} + X^{2s - \frac{1}{2}k(k + 1)}.$$

The now proven Main Conjecture in Vinogradov's Mean Value Theorem is that this lower bound is essentially an upper bound. More precisely, the conjecture was:

> **Conjecture:** For every $\varepsilon > 0$, $$J_{s, k}(X) \lesssim_{\varepsilon, s, k} X^{\varepsilon}(X^{s} + X^{2s - \frac{1}{2}k(k + 1)}).$$

This conjecture follows from classical methods for $k = 2$, first proven by Wooley for $k = 3$ using efficient congruencing in 2014 and then proven by Bourgain, Demeter, and Guth for $k \geq 4$ using decoupling methods in 2015.

My question is: when did this conjecture as stated above first appear in the literature?

Looking through Vinogradov's 1935 paper *"New estimates for Weyl sums"*, it seems that this conjecture is not stated. The term "Vinogradov's Mean Value Theorem" referring to any bound of the form $J_{s, k}(X)\lesssim X^{2s - \frac{1}{2}k(k + 1) + \Delta_{s, k}}$ for some $\Delta_{s, k}$ positive and $s \gtrsim k^{2}\log k$ seems to appear in print as early as 1947 or 1948 in these two works by Hua:

1. Page 49 of the Russian version of his *Additive theory of prime numbers* (http://mi.mathnet.ru/eng/tm1019)
2. In Hua's paper *"An improvement of Vinogradov's mean-value theorem and several applications"* (https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/os-20.1.48)

Though in both, it seems to imply that this term was in use as early as 1940. However neither also state the conjecture as mentioned above.